# How to prevent volume keys and camera key from waking up phone in Android?

Tags: android, camera, key, volume

I have an activity that I want to show up when the phone goes to sleep. However, the phone wakes up when I press the volume buttons or the camera button.

I tried using the dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) method, but it doesn't prevent the phone from waking up.

How else can I disable that functionality?

Thanks,

Comment: Please define "wakes up". Do you mean that the screen turns on?

Comment: yes as in the screen turns on

Answer (score 0):

I heard that waking behaviour is defined on framework level - in policy.jar or somewhere else. So your issue will require modifying system itself. Check also http://forum.samdroid.net/f42/disable-every-button-wake-up-2124/